# Azure AD Graph client library batch processing

Tags: azure, batch-processing, azure-sdk-.net, azure-ad-graph-api

Could some one tell me whether I can use the batch processing to add group memberships?

if yes can you please give me an example

thanks in advance

kind regards,

Snegha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing), Graph API support batch processing. The [Microsoft Azure Active Directory Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) support batch processing.

You can find a lot of samples to use the Azure AD Graph API here :

- [Azure Samples for active directory](https://github.com/Azure-Samples?query=active-directory)

Especially you have a full sample on most of the actions that you can perform with the Graph API here :

- [Call the Azure AD Graph API from a native client](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console) (search for "Batch Operations" in the [program.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/blob/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/Program.cs) file).

Unfortunately batch processing is not working for navigation properties or at least I did not find a way to make it work...

So let's have a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing).

> Graph API support for [OData](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/) batch requests:
>
> - A query is a single query or function invocation.
> - A change set is a group of one or more insert, update, or delete operations, action invocations, or service invocations.
> - A batch is a container of operations, including one or more change sets and query operations.
>
> The Graph API supports a subset of the functionality defined by the 
>   [OData](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/) specification:
>
> - A single batch can contain a maximum of five queries and/or change sets combined.
> - A change set can contain a maximum of one source object modification and up to 20 add-link and delete-link operations
>     combined. All operations in the change set must be on a single source
>     entity.

Here is the batch request syntax :

```
https://graph.windows.net/TenantName/$batch?api-version=1.6
```

A batch request is sent to the server with a single **POST** directive.

The payload is a **multi-part MIME message** containing the batch and its constituent queries and change sets. The payload includes two types of MIME boundaries:

- A **batch boundary** separates each query and/or change set in the batch.
- A **change set boundary** separates individual operations within a change set.

**An individual request within a change set is identical to a request made when that operation is called by itself.** ([here is a sample request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing#sample-request))

You can find here the full sample code : [azure-active-directory-batchprocessing](https://github.com/CrazyTuna/azure-active-directory-batchprocessing)
So Basically, you need to obtain the authentication token:

```
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantName.onmicrosoft.com";
var resource = "https://graph.windows.net/";
var clientId = "ClientId of the application in the Azure Active Directory";
var clientSecret = "ClientSecret of the application in the Azure Active Directory";

var token = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false).AcquireToken(resource,
        new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret)).AccessToken;
```

In your question you'd like to add member to a group ([see Graph API Documentation on groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations#AddGroupMembers)):

```
// Get the objectId of the group
var groupId = ...

// Get the member ids you'd like to add to the group
var memberIds = ...
```

Here is the code to add members to a group:

```
private static async Task AddMemberToGroup(string token, string groupId, IList<string> memberIds)
{
    if (memberIds.Count > 100)
    {
        // A batch can contain up to 5 changesets. Each changeset can contain up to 20 operations.
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot send more than 100 operation in an batch");
    }

    var batch = new BatchRequest("https://graph.windows.net/MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com");

    // A changeset can contain up to 20 operations
    var takeCount = 20;
    var skipCount = 0;
    var take = memberIds.Skip(skipCount).Take(takeCount).ToList();
    while (take.Count > 0)
    {
        AddChangeset(batch, groupId, take);
        skipCount += takeCount;
        take = memberIds.Skip(skipCount).Take(takeCount).ToList();
    }

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
        var response = await client.SendAsync(batch.Request);
    }
}

private static void AddChangeset(BatchRequest batch, string groupId, IEnumerable<string> memberIds)
{
    var changeset = batch.AddChangeSet();
    foreach (var memberId in memberIds)
    {
        // Create the HttpRequest to add a member to a group
        var request = AddMemberToGroupRequest(groupId, memberId);

        // Add the operation to the changeset
        changeset.AddOperation(request);
    }
}

private static HttpRequestMessage AddMemberToGroupRequest(string groupId, string memberId)
{
    // Create a request to add a member to a group
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
        $"https://graph.windows.net/MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/groups/{groupId}/$links/members?api-version=1.6");

    // Create the body of the request
    var jsonBody =
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new DirectoryObject($"https://graph.windows.net/MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/directoryObjects/{memberId}"));

    // Set the content
    request.Content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    // Return the request
    return request;
}

public class BatchRequest
{
    private readonly MultipartContent _batchContent;

    public BatchRequest(string tenantUrl)
    {
        // Create the batch request
        Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
            $"{tenantUrl}/$batch?api-version=1.6");

        // Initializes the batch content
        _batchContent = new MultipartContent("mixed", "batch_" + Guid.NewGuid());
        Request.Content = _batchContent;
    }

    public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; }

    public ChangeSet AddChangeSet()
    {
        // Create a new changeset
        var changeSet = new ChangeSet();

        // Add the content of the changeset to the batch
        _batchContent.Add(changeSet.Content);

        // return the changeset
        return changeSet;
    }

    public HttpMessageContent CreateOperation(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var content = new HttpMessageContent(request);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/http");
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
        return content;
    }
}

public class ChangeSet
{
    public ChangeSet()
    {
        Content = new MultipartContent("mixed", "changeset_" + Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    public MultipartContent Content { get; }

    public void AddOperation(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var operationContent = new HttpMessageContent(request);
        operationContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/http");
        operationContent.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
        Content.Add(operationContent);
    }
}

public class DirectoryObject
{
    public DirectoryObject(string url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }
        public string url { get; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, I did the same but I want to do the same operation in batch for 20 records(linking groups to users) and thats where im struggling with it.

Comment: do you want to add 20 users to the same group ? would you like to explain what you want to do exactly please ?

Comment: I want to link more than 100 users to a different group. but due to performance issue i would like to make use of batch operation.

Comment: For the moment the Azure AD Graph client does not implement batch processing, are you ok to use the Graph API directly ?

Comment: ok, could you please let me know how to use my above scenario in graph api?

Comment: Have you seen this article ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing. I am going to prepare a sample code for batch processing.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Thomas, one more question will that be possible to do in c#?

Comment: thanks for your help and I shall try to do the same in my scenario. will update you if i've any questions.

Comment: Hi Thomas, i've a doubt on the above sample. I get a error message "One or more added object references already exist for the following modified properties: 'members'" and so it looks like if I link groups to users and if user from the list already linked to that group i get the above error message and the rest is not linking to that group due to this error message. is this the way batch processing does or I'm wrong? can you please help me with this?

Comment: Need to have a look tomorrow morning, my first thought is that a batch operation succeeds or fails globally

Comment: It looks like if one operation fails in the changeset,  I mean 1 out of 20 operations then the whole operation in that changeset is rollback'ed. this is what mentioned in the document  "When an operation inside a change set fails, a single response fragment will be returned for the entire change set and that fragment will contain the status code and response body associated with the failed operation."   is there any way to validate the response because right now its just a text and not as a xml or json to validate the response on each changeset.